update alpine.js data variable on htmx form submit response
I'm using HTMX and Alpine.js on a form like
<form x-data="{submitted: false}" @submit.prevent="submitted = true" hx-on:htmx:after-request="submitted = false" hx-post hx-swap="none">

    {% csrf_token %}
    <p x-text="submitted"></p>

    {% include "style-guide/components/input.html" with form=form name="email" label="Email" placeholder="Email" %}

    <div id="password1"></div>

    <button type="submit" class="mt-4 btn bg-gradient-primary w-100" :disabled="submitted">
          Authenticate
      <i x-show="submitted" class="fa-solid fa-spinner fa-spin ms-2"></i>
    </button>
</form>

When the form is submitted, the submitted variable is set to true inside @submit.prevent to disable the button and show the spinner.
I want to set the submitted to false when the HTMX response is complete.
For this I tried using hx-on:htmx:after-request="submitted = false" but this is not working.
Replacing submitted = false with alert('submitted') works fine but the variable is not updating.
How can I update the alipne.js data variable on HTMX event?

htmx can't access to the AlpineJs object and to its properties, but you can intercept the event raised by htmx using AlpineJs and then update the submitted property:
<form x-data="{submitted: false}"
      @submit.prevent="submitted = true"
      @htmx:after-request.camel="submitted = false"
      hx-post
      hx-swap="none"
>

The event raised by htmx is htmx:afterRequest and since html attributes are case insensitive, Alpine allows you to specify the event name in the kebab-case but it considers the camel-case when the .camel modifier is used

That works... Thank you! :) @TUPKAP
